# redirect route /login if logged in

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make that when entering the page / login and is already logged in, direct the user to another page.

provider/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::if('CheckIfLogged', function () {
        return $value > 0;
    });
}
```

middleware/CheckIfLogged.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class CheckIfLogged
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $value = Session::get('user_id');
        if ($value > 0)
        return redirect()->route('inicio');

    }
}
```

kernel.php

```
'check' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\CheckIfLogged::class,
```

login.blade.php

```
@CheckIfLogged
//content
@endCheckIfLogged
```

But when accessing /login I am returning Error

```
Class 'App \ Providers \ Blade' not found
```

Comment: have you included the `Blade` facade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `auth` like this

```
@if(Auth::user())
 // your code here
@endif
```

and if in controller or anywhere else use it first like this ..

```
use Auth;

if(Auth::user())
{
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm using another authentication, through session and api.